# Play Billing Library v1.0 Expired Subscription

Tags: java, android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am using `Play Billing Library v1.0` for one of my android application for subscription.

```
if (billingResponse == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
    Purchase.PurchasesResult result = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
    if (result.getPurchasesList().size() > 0) {
        if (result.getPurchasesList().get(0).getSku().equals(constant.sku_subscription_weekly)) {
            premium= 2;
        }
```

I am getting sku like above and providing benefit according to it on splash Screen. I have doubt that if membership expires what will happen in this ? It will return sku still ? I have tried to test using tester account and its not returning sku if we cancel it, but I am not sure for real purchase, there no any method for test real purchase below 7 days and I do not want wait for 7 days to test, Anyone can please confirm me about it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the subscription expires you will not receive SKU in `getPurchaseList`. If the user is subscribed to only one subscription then `getPurchaseList` will return **zero**.

Handle subscription expired with `else`

```
if (result.getPurchasesList().size() > 0) {
    if (result
            .getPurchasesList()
            .get(0)
            .getSku()
            .equals(constant.sku_subscription_weekly)) {
        premium = 2;
    } else {
        // TODO: subscription expired
    }
} else {
    // TODO: subscription expired
}
```

Comment: Hi! If subscription expires, I will not receive SKU in getPurchaseList Right ? I have doubt in this. Let me know if You clear it again. Thanks

Comment: Yes. You won't get SKU in getPurchaseList.